# Programmatically email an image with some subviews but not others?

Tags: objective-c, ios, rendering

I'm working on something that will create an email and attach an image of the screen for the user to send.  I'm using the following code to create and attach the image.

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([self.view frame].size);
    [[self.view layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([self.view bounds].size);
    [myImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, [self.view bounds].size.width,[self.view bounds].size.height)];
    myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
    [mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"blah"];
```

However, this includes all of the subviews, and I want to exclude a toolbar and a segmented view, leaving only the view above the toolbar and the text field in that view.  I've tagged all the relevant views and subviews, but how do I use those tags to create an image that includes what I want and excludes what I don't want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you render the image, set all the views you don't want to show to hidden.
I have several apps that do this exact same thing, and that's what I do.

`renderInContext` and related functions basically take a screenshot, so [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG)

Comment: Thanks!  That's a far simpler and more elegant solution than what I feared it would be.

Comment: A further question:  That does what I want, but now the area where the toolbar was shows as a blank gray space.  How do I get the UIView above it to expand to fill the whole view (without, of course, deleting the other subviews I want to include)?

Comment: Change the frame to the view's current frame + whatever additional area you need to fill the toolbar's area. You can do this with `CGRectMake`